# Duplicate MEF export definitions in F#

Tags: .net, f#, mef

I have this relatively simple program:

```
open System
open System.ComponentModel.Composition
open System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting
open System.Reflection

module Config =
    [<Export("Timer.Delay")>]
    let Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    let container = new CompositionContainer(catalog)
    let delay = container.GetExportedValue<TimeSpan> "Timer.Delay"

    printfn "Delay: %A" delay
```

But I get this error on calling `container.GetExportedValue<TimeSpan> "Timer.Delay"`:

> More than one export was found that matches the constraint:
>
> ContractName     Timer.Delay
>
> RequiredTypeIdentity System.TimeSpan

Inspecting the `catalog.Parts` collection, I see two parts, each with a single `ExportDefinition`. The first one for `Program+Config`, which I would expect to find, and one for `<StartupCode$Remote>.$Program` (note the assembly name is `Remote`):

[image: catalog.Parts]

Wrapping the `main` function in a `module Program` does not change this behavior, nor does separating these modules into different files. Does anybody know why this F# program is generating a second export definition? And how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fiddling with it for a little bit, I think I've figured it out. My guess is that when the F# compiler sees an untargeted attribute on a property like the one above, it actually emits *two* attributes, one for the property and one for the field. It's probably also relevant that the `ExportAttribute` may be applied to properties and fields. Specifying a target on the attribute seems to resolve this issue.

This will generate the `Program+Config` part:

```
module Config =
    [<property: Export("Timer.Delay")>]
    let Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0)
```

This will generate the `<StartupCode$Remote>.$Program` part:

```
module Config =
    [<field: Export("Timer.Delay")>]
    let Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0)
```

Both of these will solve my problem, but the first one seems better, since it binds the `Export` attribute to a member of the actual module, rather than to some compiler-generated code.